# Initializing some bytes in RAM using Assembler

Tags: assembly, directive, 8051

In 8051 Assembly programming, we use `ORG 00H` to tell the assembler that the code that follows the instruction `ORG 00H` should be placed from location 00H in **ROM**. Is there any way to tell the assembler to start placing the code from a particular location in internal RAM?

Comment: No because you can't execute code from RAM. Also you'd need a loader or some initialization code that would copy the section from ROM into RAM.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? This sounds like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't know assembler instruction set for 8051. But, aren't there some instructions to load a value from ROM into a register, and one to store it to RAM, one by one? Then it should be possible through a loop.

Comment: Do you want to store executable code into RAM or data?

Comment: No, the _assembler_ will generate an Intel HEX file containing machine code and the address this code should be placed. When you flash your code into the micro the flashing program only access the code memory. The flashing program may have access to the RAM part of the memory but it can't upload an HEX file, you can merely send one or more bytes at a given address manually. If you want to "initialize" some byte in RAM why not use `MOV/MOVX` instructions doing that right at the beginning of your code ?